# How to call a view with many parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I am trying to create a very simple custom view for my application.
Lets imagine I have a simply model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    pass

class Company(models.Model):
    Title = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    pass
```

I would like to display a list of objects. On one url - list of person, on another - list of companies. So I create simply views:

```
def PersonListView (request):
    _persons = Person.objects.all()
    context = {
        "object_list": _persons
    }
    return render (request, "PersonListView.html", context)

def CompanyListView (request):
    _companies = Person.objects.all()
    context = {
        "object_list": _companies
    }
    return render (request, "CompanyListView.html", context)
```

Then add path to urls - /Person for list of persons and /Company for list of companies.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/Person', PersonListView), 
    path('/Company', CompanyListView)
]
```

All working well. But I already have a questions:

1. Why my view function have a *request* variable, but I can call this function from urls without defining this variable?
2. Why I can't use this syntax `path('/Person', PersonListView())`? What is wrong with this brackets?

And another part of my question.
But then I decided to make some refactoring - I intended to use **one view** both for person and companies, so I have to pass a variable *context* to view function. And I basically know how to do it:

```
def ObjectList (request, _context):
    _objects = _context.objects.all()
    data = {
        "object_list": _objects
    }
    return render (request, "ListView.html", data)
```

Here _context - concrete class (Person or Company).

My problem is in urls.py I have to call ObjectList and pass 2 variables:

_context - there is no problem here, I know how to do it

and **request**.

Here I faced a wall, because I don't understand how can I pass it to my function. If I just let it empty, I have an error
**"ObjectList() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'"**

3. So how can I fix it? SHould I somehow pass it from my urls? Is there a way to use a view function with multiple arguments?

Here is the traceback:

```
Internal Server Error: /Entities/Person/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Work\Python\virtualenvs\TestProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "D:\Work\Python\virtualenvs\TestProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "D:\Work\Python\virtualenvs\TestProject\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: ObjectList() got multiple values for argument '_context'
[25/Jul/2019 00:25:37] "GET /Entities/Person/ HTTP/1.1" 500 62910
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second question answers your first. You don't *call* the view from the URL; Django does that internally when it encounters a matching request. If you try to call it from there, then you get the error you see.

I don't understand though why you think you need to pass request from the URL in the third question. You don't, that's the whole point of your questions 1 and 2.

Your URL pattern should either capture the arguments for the view, or pass them as the third parameter to `path`. So, in your case, you could use a single pattern which captures the variable:

```
path('/<str:object_type>/', object_list, name='object_list')
```

and then:

```
def object_list(request, object_type):
    types = {'Person': models.Person, 'Company': models.Company}
    if object_type not in types:
        raise Http404
    objects = types[object_type].objects.all()
```

Alternatively, use two separate URL patterns and pass the type as [the third parameter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions) explicitly:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/Person', object_list_view, {'object_type': Person}, name='person_list'), 
    path('/Company', object_list_view, {'object_type': Company}, name='company_list'),
]
```

and your view can be:

```
def object_list(request, object_type):
    objects = object_type.objects.all()
```

Finally, though, for this very simple use case you should consider using a [generic list view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/); then you wouldn't need to define any views at all:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
urlpatterns = [
    path('/Person', ListView.as_view(model=Person)), 
    path('/Company', ListView.as_view(model=Company))
]
```

Comment: I try as u propose in alternative approach (with 3d param), but unfortanutally got an error:
ObjectList() got multiple values for argument 'object_type'
I tried to use this approach only for one URL

Comment: Which version did you try?

Comment: I have installed version 2.2.3

Comment: seems that this feature is not working as in django docs.
Or there are some other restriction I don't know about

Comment: No, which version of my answer? I gave three alternatives; which one did you try? Show the exact code you used, and the full error traceback, as an edit to your question.

Comment: I chose an approach with third params, after your words "Alternatively, use two separate URL patterns..."
I did exactly as u described(and as described in django docs)
I defined a class base view and call it in path ```path('Person/', ObjectListVIew.ObjectList, {'_context': Person})```
here is my View
```
class ObjectListVIew(View):
        
    @classmethod
    def ObjectList (request, _context):
        _objects = _context.objects.all()
        data = {
            "object_list": _objects
        }
        return render (request, "ListView.html", data)
```

Comment: sorry i don't know how to format text in commetns here

Comment: add a traceback in my question post

Comment: That wasn't even vaguely what I said to do. Please follow the example *exactly*. (And, as I also did, post your code as an edit to the question, not in a comment.)

Comment: I am sorry, but you use different names of view functions in path() and in function definition. Should I follow this exact way?
I changed a little your answer, but sanse the same.
anyway thanks for help.

Comment: Just remove that class and make Objectlist a standalone function as I showed.

Comment: Is it impossible to implement similar logic to method inside a class?

Comment: You could, but what would be the benefit? You're not using any of the class functionality. Anyway, the third example I showed you was exactly using a class.